# Am I loading datatable twice & update row item with boolean value

Tags: vb.net, datatable, sql-update, spreadsheet

I call the following function in a module

Public Function GetExcelData(ByVal ExcelFile As String) As System.Data.DataTable

Then I have the following code

```
            If openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            gblCompName = openFileDialog1.FileName
        End If

        Dim reader As New DataTableReader(GetExcelData(gblCompName))
        Dim table As New DataTable

        table.Load(reader)
        table.Columns.Add("Single", GetType(Boolean), False)
        table.Columns.Add("CouplesInFinal", GetType(Int32))
        table.Columns.Add("EvtNum", GetType(String))
        table.Columns.Add("EvtStruct", GetType(Int32))
        table.Columns.Add("EvtCplID", GetType(Int32))
        table.Columns.Add("CouplesInClass", GetType(Int32))
        table.Columns.Add("Valid", GetType(Boolean), True)

        Dim result() As DataRow = table.Select("[class]" Like "Single")
        For Each row In result
            If row.Item("Class") Like "Single" Then
                table.Rows(0)("Single") = True
            End If
        Next

        DataGridView1.DataSource = table
```

My logic tells me I'm loading the table twice & the data row field "Single" is boolean which I'm trying to update to True if string field "class" is like "Single"

I realize it's 2 questions in one but it seems to load quite slowly & it's all one form procedure. Any advice on this will be very welcome thanks

Comment: Do you not trust your `table.Select`? You do the same thing again in your if statement.. You are only changing the first row again and again with `table.Rows(0)("Single") = True`

Comment: @Mary My bad. I had rem'd that out in testing & copied/pasted the code back. Either way the datagrid view doesn't show the updated field as true where the text of field "class" has the word "Single" in it.

Comment: I discovered that the expression False on the Columns.Add("Single" statement causes the field to be made read only. Now I just need to find out if I am actually loading the datatable twice

Comment: The 3rd argument in `Columns.Add` is a [DataColumn Expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for computed columns.  Instead of setting it to `False` thus preventing any change in row values, set it to "[Class] Like '*Single*'".  Now the value will update on its own and you can eliminated the `For-Each` that will not work anyways.  Also since you appear to want a case-sensitive comparison set `table.CaseSensitive = True`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim reader As New DataTableReader(GetExcelData(gblCompName))
Dim table As New DataTable
```

Without seeing GetExcelData it is hard to say if you are filling twice. If this function returns a populated DataTable then

```
Dim table as DataTable = GetExcelData(gblCompName)
```

and delete the table.Load and the DataReader.
Here is my version of updating a DataTable against my sample database.

```
Private Sub TestDataTableUpdate()
        Try
            Using cmd As New SqlCommand("Select * From Coffees", CoffeeCn)
                Dim dt As New DataTable
                CoffeeCn.Open()
                Using dr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
                    dt.Load(dr)
                End Using
                CoffeeCn.Close()
                For index As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
                    If dt.Rows(index)("Name").ToString = "Cinnamon Stick" Then
                        dt.Rows(index)("Roast") = "N/A"
                    End If
                Next
                'The above does not update the database
                Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd) 'provides the connection and Select command
                Dim sqlCB As New SqlCommandBuilder(da) 'Associates the DataAdapter to the command builder
                sqlCB.GetUpdateCommand() 'Retrieve the update command for the DataAdapter
                'Note: the DataAdapter opens and closes the connection for you
                da.Update(dt) 'This updates the database by finding the changed rows in the datatable
                'and running the Update command
                dt.AcceptChanges() 'Reset the row status to unchanged
                DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        Finally
            CoffeeCn.Close()
        End Try
    End Sub
```

PS. I am self-taught also.

Comment: The GetExcelData reads an Excel spreadsheet into the public datatable "table". If I try your suggestion I get the "value of type datatable cannot be converted to strings

Comment: Are you referring to `Dim table as DataTable = GetExcelData(gblCompName)`? table is a DataTable and your function returns a DataTable. How could strings get into it?

Answer (score 0):

The table update method that I got to work is

```
                Dim i As Integer = 0
            For i = 0 To table.Rows.Count - 1
                If table.Rows(i)("Class") Like "*Single*" Then
                    table.Rows(i)("Single") = True
                End If
            Next
```

I took out the ",False" on this line table.Columns.Add("Single", GetType(Boolean)